# Dell Driver Support for Latitude E6320 Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, 32-bit, dell-latitude

I recently did a reinstall of Windows 7 Enterprise on a Dell Latitude E6320, which is a 64 bit system. After the install process, and doing typical Windows Update stuff, I looked at my Device Manager and found that I had devices which were missing drivers.

My missing drivers:

[image]

After going to the [Dell Support site](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/usgen1/DriversHome/) and looking at the files, and doing some sleuthing I found the following support document:

> http://downloads.dell.com/utility/Latitude%20E-Family%20%20Mobile%20Precision%20Re-Image%20How-To%20Guide%20-%20A03%20Rev%203%200.pdf

This document hints in appendix C that the Broadcom USH is the Control Point Security and the Unknown device is Micro freefall sensor. The network controller is my wireless, as I cannot connect wirelessly, and the final missing driver I am not sure.

Attempting to install the control point security exe on the support page will not work. After downloading, I am given the message that I am attempting to install a 32 bit driver on a 64 bit machine EVEN THOUGH I selected the win7 64 bit option from the support page. Beyond that, some of the drivers (Which are confusing to read and hard to understand what they do) and the system utilities which are supposedly supposed to make this process simpler will either a) not run because they are 32 bit exe's or b) the support page cannot find the file attempted to download.

Is there anything I can do to get (at the very least) my wireless running, but idealistically all of my drivers. A solution which assumes Dell is completely incompetent would be ideal. :P  Some forums have said that I should download the chipset driver, others say to get the system utility file (DSS_UTIL_WIN_R282536.EXE). I have had no luck as of yet...

Comment: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/ca/en/cabsdt1/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?c=ca&s=bsd&cs=cabsdt1&l=en&DriverId=R308326

Answer (score 2):

The R308494.exe also worked for Windows 8 Pro 64-BIT system, you can find it here: http://ftp.dell.com/security/ it did prompted for an update, didn't run it yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a file named `Dell_ControlVault_A08_R308494.exe` helped with 'Broadcom USH' and `ST-MICROELECTRONICS_FREE-FAL_A10_R309372.exe` (fall sensor) helped with 'Unknown device' (I had to install it even that the fall sensor was switched off in BIOS).

Comment: Hi Boryn, can you maybe expand how you came about that resolution? It might not be the same for the OP, and it would be helpful to future visitors to explain the *how* as well.

Answer (score 0):

These are a pain the ass.  More than likely the Broadcom USH is NOT your issue.  The free fall sensor more than likely is.  I wouldn't even attempt to install the control point.  Worst piece of digital filth joke ware I've ever come across.

The SM Bus is going to be you chipset.  You want to get the most current chipset drivers, basically three of the 4 listed under the chipset section.  Skip UTIL_WIN_R304257.EXE

Then go back to the APPLICATIONS section and get this one for the sensor ST-MICROELECTRONICS_FREE-FAL_A10_R309372.exe (5MB)

Then under Network get NIC_DRVR_WIN_A01_R294111.EXE unless you sprang for the intel card.  Once you have those guys knocked out you should be clean.  But if anything else still lacks just go to Devman, then the properties of the device then to the details tab.  Then drop the selector to Hardware IDs and then just copy the stuff you see below into a Google and that will likely find the correct component so you then know what driver you still need.  The Broadcom USH COULD come into it but I think that will be knocked out along with the SMS Bus.

Comment: And yes as the cat above noted you do want the AMT stuff (Like I said 3 of the 4 listed files under Chipset heading)

Comment: I cannot download chipset file: Dell-Driver 
Intel_Chipset-Software-Insta_A04_R304291.exe (2MB). Says File Not found. Anyone able to download this?

Comment: mirror.symnds.com/software/ftp.dell.com/chipset Found the chipset file @ this link. downloaded and installed. then downloaded and installed AMT drivers. remaining... Broadcom USH, Network Controller, Unknown device –

Answer (score 0):

This site has the drivers you are looking for:
http://mirror.symnds.com/software/ftp.dell.com/chipset/Intel_Chipset-Software-Insta_A04_R304291.exe

I assume you had issues with downloading the input software for the trackpad as well:
http://mirror.symnds.com/software/ftp.dell.com/input/DELL_MULTI-TOUCH-TOUCHPAD_A10_R315893.exe

Seems to be a pretty good site for alternate Dell downloads.

Cheers!
AP

Answer (score 0):

The Dell Latitude E6320 comes with one of **3** wifi cards.  My machine came with an Intel N 6205.  I downloaded the Intel WiFi Link 6205 drivers from the Dell site and everything works fine now.

I suspect the OP may have the same card?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and I've managed to solve it with following drivers:

- Broadcom USH - Dell_ControlVault_A08_R308494.exe
- Unknow device - ST-MICROELECTRONICS_FREE-FAL_A10_R309372.exe
- Network Controller - [Intel® 82579 Gigabit Ethernet Controller](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18713&ProdId=3299&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%207%20%2864-bit%29*&DownloadType=Drivers#help)

Comment: You only provided a source for a single driver.  This answer would be more helpful if you supplied a source for the driver.

Answer (score -1):

[Install your chipset](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=T4TP8&FileId=2731102637) and [Intel AMT drivers](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=WTT04&FileId=2731103350), restart the PC then tell me what is missing in Device Manager. Install chipset first, then AMT

Comment: Unfortunately, I still cannot download the files. Clicking download says file not found. download and install asks me to contact the vendor... Are you able to download these files?

Comment: http://mirror.symnds.com/software/ftp.dell.com/chipset/

Found the chipset file @ this link. downloaded and installed. then downloaded and installed AMT drivers.

remaining...

Broadcom USH,
Network Controller,
Unknown device

Comment: now only broadcom and unknown device are unavailable

Comment: broadcom is usually a network driver, try this utility for the unknown...http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html